# how can i make this merge/ update statement more efficient , its taking too much time

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
MERGE INTO ////////1  GFO
           USING 
             (SELECT *
  FROM
    (SELECT facto/////rid,
      p-Id,
      PRE/////EDATE,
      RU//MODE,
      cre///date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY facto/////id ORDER BY cre///te DESC) col
    FROM ///////////2
    ) x
  WHERE x.col = 1) UFD 
            ON (GFO.FACTO-/////RID=UFD.FACTO////RID)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
            SET 
            GFO.PRE////DATE=UFD.PRE//////DATE
            WHERE UFD.CRE/////DATE IS NOT NULL
            AND UFD.RU//MODE= 'S'
            AND GFO.P////ID=:2
```

hi every1, my above merge statement is taking too long , it has to run  40 times on table 1 using table2 each having 4millions plus records, for 40 different p--id, please suggest more efficient way as currently its taking 40+ minutes.
its updating only one colummn using a column from table2.t

i am unable to execute the query, its returning 
Error: cannot fetch last explain plan from PLAN_TABLE
[EXPLAIN PLAN IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARA3c.png)

HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT OF EXPLAIN PLAN

[cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znsso.png)

Comment: Could you show an explain plan for this query ? Just run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR MERGE ..........` and then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display)`, and then copy a resut of this query (as a text) and append it to the question.

Comment: Are there selective indexes on `GFO.P////ID`, `GFO.FACTO-/////RID`, and `UFD.FACTO////RID`?   If so, join GFO into your `SELECT` statement and apply the `GFO.P////ID=:2` filter there.

Comment: It's also unclear to me why this would need to be run 40 times rather than being run once for all 40 `p--id` values with an extra condition in the `on`.

Comment: i have added explain plan image, unable to fetch explain plan...click on the    link

Comment: What is a type of `CREATE_DATE` column in UDT_FGA_DUEDATE table ? The explain plan shows, that oracle is using `internal function` while ordering rows from this table. This probably means, that this column is casted from one type to some another type.

Answer (score 1):

The shown plan seems to by OK, the observed problem stems from the LOOP over P_ID that do not scale.

I assume you performs something like this (strongly simplified) - assuming the P_ID to be processed are in table `TAB_PID`

```
begin 
for cur in (select p_id from tab_pid) loop
 merge INTO tab1 USING tab2 ON (tab1.r_id = tab2.r_id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET tab1.col1=tab2.col1 WHERE p_id = cur.p_id;
 end loop;
end;
/
```

HASH JOIN on large tables (in NO PARALLEL mode) with elapsed time 60 seconds is not a catastrophic result. But looping 40 times makes your 40 minutes.

So I'd sugesst to try to integrate the loop in the MERGE statement, without knowing details something like this (mayby you'll need also ajdust the MERGE JOIN condition).

```
 merge INTO tab1 USING tab2 ON (tab1.r_id = tab2.r_id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET tab1.col1=tab2.col1 
   WHERE p_id in (select p_id from tab_pid);
```